# Show and Hide product li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, show-hide

I have a list

```
<ul class="products">
   <li class="products">first</li>
   <li class="products">second</li>
   <li class="products">third</li>
   <li class="products">fourth</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to use jquery to:
1-hide other li s when user clicks on one except the clicked one.
2-show all li s when user clicks again on the active li.

this is the script:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".products li.active").click(function(){
    $(".products li").show("slow");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
$(".products li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".products li:not(.active)").hide("slow");
});
});
```

it works for the first step, but when user clicks on active li nothing changes.

Comment: `$(".products").on("click", "li.active", function(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $(".products li").click(function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
          //this is already active, show all
          $(".products li").show("slow");
          $(this).removeClass("active");
      } else {
          //this is not active yet, make active and hide all others
          $(this).addClass("active");
          $(".products li:not(.active)").hide("slow");
      }
   });
});
```

[Live demo available here on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3kvR/)

Answer (score 1):

Those selectors are evaluated at the moment you bind the event - so the first `click` event won't be bound to anything. Use a single function instead and check the class inside that function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".products li").click(function() {
        if($(this)).hasClass('active') {
            $(".products li").show("slow");
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".products li:not(.active)").hide("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Oh, and use the DOMReady (`$(document).ready()`) event instead of the WindowLoaded event...

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to have 2 click events :

```
$(document).load(function(){
    $(".products li").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("active"){
           $(".products li").show("slow");
           $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
        else{
           $(this).addClass("active");
           $(".products li:not(.active)").hide("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Haha! We both answered with the same solution at the same time. You've got a typo at line 3 at ("active"){}. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$(".products li.active").live("click",function(){
    $(".products li").show("slow");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});

$(".products li:not('.active')").live("click",function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".products li:not(.active)").hide("slow");
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZEBr/)
​